# What's a word for a person who has one or more unlikely events happen to them that are neither beneficial nor detrimental?

Tags: single-word-requests

The work 'lucky' often implies that the unlikely event is beneficial. However this is the closest I can think of besides something like 'non-unlucky' which is ambiguous at best.

Example:

> If you are __________ you may get two of the same image. Do not be deceived, the images are both picked from a random pool separately.

Comment: Normal.  Every day many unlikely things happen to you.  Most, however, are of no consequence to you, one way or the other.  Eg, a particular traffic signal turns green just as you approach.  The chances of that happening may be one in a thousand.  But a thousand other things that could have happened didn't.

Comment: @hotlicks I agree, but I still find a need for this word sometimes. Think unlikely event that is significant for some other reason (and therefor not normal). See my example.

Comment: "statistically jinxed"

Comment: @shelvacu "happenstance prone;" "coincidence prone"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is one word to cover unlikely events that are "neutral" in their impact, however if they are really significant, and happen more than once, you can use *drama magnet*, but that tends to be for more unfortunate events.

For good fortune there is *lucky* of course, as an adjective, or more neutrally, perhaps *uncanny* as an adjective.